# Create a projected raster from array with python gdal

Tags: python, projection, gdal

I've got a processed image array from UAV and want to write it into a projected tiff. I am aware with the array to tiff writting process with python gdal, however not sure how to project it correctly.

I have got the central GPS, UAV height, pixel size of the image array, the array is northward. The orginal UAV image's metadata can not be recognized by gdal, so I have to extract them out and then rearrange them to project the array.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague.  The process you need to look into is called "ortho-rectification".  You should read about the process and then break it down into stages.  Then, figure out the specific pieces you have and don't have.

Fundamentally, in order to create an ortho-image, you need a digital elevation model (DEM), intrinsic camera parameters, and extrinsic parameters (pose).  You can find documentation on the algorithm online or in a standard Remote Sensing book.

Another option is if your camera provides Rational Polynomial Coefficients (RPCs), which I assume is no.

Generic Amazon Search of Remote Sensing Books

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=remote+sensing